# How to add Shopify abandoned checkout entries by using APPs/API

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

Is there any way I can add abandoned checkout entries through APP using the Shopify Rest API?
Currently I can only access these 2 [APIs](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2021-10/resources/abandoned-checkouts#top), count and list.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create abandoned checkout using Rest API, but you can do this with the help of Shopify Storefront Graphql API. You can use the below mutation to create an abandoned cart.

```
mutation createAbondonedCart{
  checkoutCreate(
    input: {email: "user@example.com", shippingAddress: {address1: "Abc", address2: "Xyz", city: "Mumbai", company: "TEST", country: "India", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", phone: "000000000", province: "Maharashtra", zip: "400025"}, note: "Handle with Care", lineItems: [{quantity: 10, variantId: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/56768575857"}]}
  ) {
    checkout {
      id
    }
    checkoutUserErrors {
      code
      field
      message
    }
  }
}
```

For running this mutation, generate a Shopify storefront access token by creating a custom app inside the store or by building a sales channel app.

For the custom app, you will need read and write checkout permission of the storefront.